# Magento 2 Cart count

Tags: magento2, cart

I am using below code in my custom phtml

```
$object =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $object->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
$cartCount = count( $cart );
if($cartCount > 0){
    echo $cartCount;
    } else{
        echo "0" ;
    }
    ?>
```

It return correct count only cart page rest all page it return 0 only

Comment: this may be because your header block caching is true

Comment: HOw i can fix this

Comment: In which block are u using this..?

Comment: In logo.phtml i added this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to override the **logo block** in  **default.xml**, if you go to core module `Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` there you have  container called **header-wrapper** inside that logo block is there, override this block in you default.xml file.

Logo block should look like below

```
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo" cacheable="false">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

In you default.xml (module/theme) you need to put this code.

`<referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo" cacheable="false">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>`

Comment: I call this way <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo-big.png</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

Comment: How i will add here

Comment: see my updated code